# How can I make the bar graph for each group separately?

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

I have the data 500 groups and each group have different no of students with their scores. I want to make the separate bar graph (in R) for each group in such a way students should be on x axix and their score on the y axis. I tried to make with ggplot2 but it generate the single bar graph for all the 500 groups. My data is in following form: Any idea how can I make it separately for each group in R?
      [image]

Comment: Give us some reproducible data and we'll show you how to do it in base R.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
dataset <- expand.grid(Group = 1:3, Student = LETTERS[1:3]) 
dataset$Score <- runif(nrow(dataset), max = 100)
dlply(dataset, ~Group, function(x){
  ggplot(x, aes(x = Student, y = Score)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`.  We `split` the dataset by the 'Group' column to create a `list`, loop through the `names` of the `list` elements, create `barplot` for each group separately and save it as a `png` file.

```
lst <- split(df1[-1], df1$Group)
invisible(lapply(names(lst), function(nm1) {
   png(paste0('barplot_', nm1, '.png'))
   barplot(setNames(lst[[nm1]]$Score, lst[[nm1]]$Student), 
                              main=paste0('barplot of Group', nm1))
   dev.off()
 }))
```

NOTE: The title (`main=`) and the file name can be changed accordingly.